# Very Simple Mirth Functionality (Version 3.1.1.7461)

Tags: javascript, mirth, transformer-model

Ok, trying to get the basics down as far as how Mirth interacts with the data.  Simple script below checking for a value and setting outbound to a hardcoded value when finished.  This is not a real life scenario, so please don't get hung up on the why....  When running this script, I receive an error:

```
[2017-05-24 02:34:34,845]  ERROR (transformer:?): TypeError: Cannot read property "EVN.1" from undefined.
```

This must be something simple, but could use some interaction if anyone cares to share.  It seems to not want to identify my HL7.

Java Script

```
var full_evn1 = msg['EVN']['EVN.1']['EVN.1.1'].toString();

if (full_evn1 = "A01" ) {
  tmp['EVN']['EVN.5']['EVN.5.1'] = "MYID" 
}
```

Comment: If that's copy-paste from your code, then in the "if" statement you are assigning "A01" value to full_evn1, not verifying it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it must be a different piece of code than the snippet you posted. You wouldn't get that error unless whatever comes *before* the EVN.1 is undefined. E4X has some special stuff where msg['EVN'] will be defined (as an empty XML object) *even if* there are no "EVN" children nodes in the parent.

Instead you probably have a separate place in your code where you're referencing something like msg['EVN'][0]['EVN.1']... The XML object supports array nature, but actually *does* return undefined when the index is incorrect.